# How can I bulk delete 1800 folders?

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell, splistitem, csv, bulk

I have a colleague who has written a powershell script to read URLs from a CSV file and create empty folders at those locations... 1800 of them. The problem is they used their own named developer account to grant permissions to the script and so all the folders are listed as Created By . We now need to delete the folders and recreate them using a system account.

Here is the code used to create the folders:

```
$allFolders = Import-Csv '..\Input\Tranche 5\Empty Folders\ATestEmptyFolders.csv'

$currentUrl = ''
foreach($folder in $allFolders)
{
    $firstUrlSplit = $folder.FullUrl -Split('/sites/')
    $secondUrlSplit = $firstUrlSplit[1] -Split('/')

    $siteUrl = $firstUrlSplit[0]+'/sites/'+$secondUrlSplit[0]+'/'
    $siteUrl
    $emptyFolderSiteRelURL = $folder.FullURL.Replace($siteUrl, '') -replace '[":*<>?\\|]', '-'
    $emptyFolderSiteRelURL

    if($siteUrl -eq $currentUrl)
    {
        Resolve-PnPFolder $emptyFolderSiteRelURL
    } else {
        Connect-PnPOnline -Url $siteUrl -UseWebLogin
        $currentUrl = $siteUrl
        Resolve-PnPFolder $emptyFolderSiteRelURL
    }    
}
```

Question: Is there a way can we use the same CSV file to bulk delete all 1800 folders so we can recreate them using a Service Account?

Comment: Can't you just create a view which filter out all the folders created by X and then set the limit to 100 items? 18 clicks and they're gone. :)

Comment: No, we need the 1800 folders created in those specific locations as targets for a data migration but the client has a requirement for them to be marked as created by a system account not a user account.